# Matplotlib: xticks labels not showing

Tags: python-2.7, matplotlib

I'm new to matplotlib and I'm having a small problem. I'm trying to make 3 plots stacked on top of each other, sharing the x axis and with 2 different y axis. 
This is my current code

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

periods = range(1,13)
n0 = [4.2, 6.7, 10.6, 51.3, 339, 45.6, 56.3, 112.9, 182.7, 185.7, 126.2, 25.39]
alp = [2.12, 2.14, 2.19, 2.35, 2.54, 2.33, 2.34, 2.43, 2.45, 2.46, 2.466, 2.249]
B = [0.045, 0.041, 0.04, 0.04, 0.057, 0.048, 0.044, 0.057, 0.054, 0.065, 0.06, 0.045]
emin = [166, 201.9, 215, 270.7, 351.8, 263.7, 302.2, 323.6, 328.7, 346.1, 279.5, 259.8]
emax = [21806, 28407, 5706, 22087, 17978, 11699, 19440, 17988, 26938, 14812, 14195, 26121]
eq = [7.8, 11.8, 13.3, 15.2, 8.87, 10.5, 13.8, 7.6, 11.5, 7.4, 6.4, 13.5]

f, (ax1, ax2, ax3) = plt.subplots(3, sharex = True)
ax1.scatter(periods, emin, c="k")
ax1.set_ylabel(r"$E_{min}")
ax1.yaxis.set_ticks(range(160, 380, 40))

ax4 = ax1.twinx()
ax4.scatter(periods, n0, c="r")
ax4.set_ylabel(r"$N_0$", color = 'r')
ax4.tick_params(colors = 'r')
ax4.yaxis.set_ticks(np.arange(20, 340, 50))

ax2.scatter(periods, emax, c="k")
ax2.set_ylabel(r"$E_{max}$")
ax2.yaxis.set_ticks(np.arange(5000, 30000, 5000))
ax5 = ax2.twinx()
ax5.scatter(periods, alpha, c="r")
ax5.set_ylabel("alp", color = 'r')
ax5.tick_params(colors = 'r')
ax5.yaxis.set_ticks(np.arange(2.1, 2.6, 0.1))

ax3.scatter(periods, eq, c="k")
ax3.set_ylabel("Eq")
ax3.yaxis.set_ticks(np.arange(6, 15, 2))
ax3.set_xlabel("Periods")
ax6 = ax3.twinx()
ax6.scatter(periods, B, c="r")
ax6.set_ylabel("B", color = 'r')
ax6.tick_params(colors = 'r')
ax6.yaxis.set_ticks(np.arange(0.02, 0.09, 0.02))
ax6.xaxis.set_ticks(range(1,13))

f.subplots_adjust(hspace = 0)
plt.setp([a.get_xticklabels() for a in f.axes[:-1]], visible=False)
plt.show()
```

But the x axis labels are not being shown. The label itself ("Periods") is fine, but the ticks aren't. I've tried to change the line

```
ax6.xaxis.set_ticks(range(1,13))
```

to every other number, but still doesn't work. Any help?
On a side note, how to rotate the y axis labels by 90 degrees so that they are horizontal? I've tried including `rotation = 90` in the ylabel but it doesn't change (though other values work).

Thanks a lot

Edit: Forgot to add, if I erase the twinx axes it works fine

Comment: Check out your second to last line..... `visible=False`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order for your x ticks to appear you need to change the second to last line and set `visible = True`. In order to rotate the y labels by 90 degrees, use `rotation =` as you are doing, but set the rotation to `0`. Doing this may make your labels and your ticks overlap. You can remove this by using the `labelpad =` in your `ax.set_ylabel()`. This is the spacing between the axis and the label.

```
f, (ax1, ax2, ax3) = plt.subplots(3, sharex = True)
ax1.scatter(periods, emin, c="k")
ax1.set_ylabel(r"$E_{min}$",rotation=0,labelpad=20)
ax1.yaxis.set_ticks(range(160, 380, 40))

ax4 = ax1.twinx()
ax4.scatter(periods, n0, c="r")
ax4.set_ylabel(r"$N_0$", color = 'r',rotation=0,labelpad=10)
ax4.tick_params(colors = 'r')
ax4.yaxis.set_ticks(np.arange(20, 340, 50))

ax2.scatter(periods, emax, c="k")
ax2.set_ylabel(r"$E_{max}$",rotation=0,labelpad=20)
ax2.yaxis.set_ticks(np.arange(5000, 30000, 5000))
ax5 = ax2.twinx()
ax5.scatter(periods, alp, c="r")
ax5.set_ylabel("alp", color = 'r',rotation=0,labelpad=15)
ax5.tick_params(colors = 'r')
ax5.yaxis.set_ticks(np.arange(2.1, 2.6, 0.1))

ax3.scatter(periods, eq, c="k")
ax3.set_ylabel("Eq",rotation=0,labelpad=20)
ax3.yaxis.set_ticks(np.arange(6, 15, 2))
ax3.set_xlabel("Periods")
ax6 = ax3.twinx()
ax6.scatter(periods, B, c="r")
ax6.set_ylabel("B", color = 'r',rotation=0,labelpad=10)
ax6.tick_params(colors = 'r')
ax6.yaxis.set_ticks(np.arange(0.02, 0.09, 0.02))
ax1.xaxis.set_ticks(np.arange(1, 13, 1))


f.subplots_adjust(hspace = 0,left=0.14,right=0.90)
plt.setp([a.get_xticklabels() for a in f.axes[:-1]], visible=True)
plt.show()
```

This produces the following plot:

[image]

You may want to experiment with the `labelpad` to get the labels exactly where you want them as the length of your tick labels are not the same for each axis.

Comment: Thanks a lot, this worked. But why the change when you add the twix command? As I understood, `plt.setp([a.get_xticklabels() for a in f.axes[:-1]], visible=False)` hid every x axis tick label except for the last one (the one on the bottom). And this works without the double axes

Comment: So it turns out that the ticks of subplot 1 and 2 are still actually there, but because `hspace = 0` we only see the bottom ones. I suppose this doesn't really matter as it produces the desired output, but I don't know why this is the case with twin axes.

Comment: Or rather, I don't know why `plt.setp([a.get_xticklabels() for a in f.axes[:-1]], visible=False)` doesn't hide the ticks of the first two subplots in this case