# How to force matplotlib to expand range for at least two ticks

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

I can't get any tick marks to appear when I have a narrow range of data and log formatting. I found a [similar problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43038107/matplotlib-xticks-labels-not-showing) that talked about forcing a minimum number of ticks and tried that solution, but it did not seem to help.

What I want to do is have the Y range be automatically expanded until at least two ticks can be included, including one major tick (so it gets a label). I can't do anything to manual or custom because a lot of different data goes through this routine and it is only rarely that the range is so tight that no labels appear.

Here is an example that preserves as much of my local environment as possible:

```
import matplotlib
import numpy as np
import pylab as plt

fig=plt.figure(figsize=(15, 20))
locmin = matplotlib.ticker.LogLocator(base=10.0,subs=(.1,.2,.3,.4,.5,.6,.7,.8,.9),numticks=15)

ax6 = plt.subplot(616)
plt.plot(np.random.random(1000)*4+14, 'b')
plt.plot(np.random.random(1000)*4+14, 'r')
plt.minorticks_on()
plt.ylabel('Y')
plt.yscale('log')

ax6.yaxis.set_minor_locator(locmin)
ax6.yaxis.set_minor_formatter(matplotlib.ticker.NullFormatter())
plt.show()
```

[image]
The result is this plot here, which has no Y labels...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the array of `major_ticks` and `minor_ticklocs`. Then find the bounds for the given scaled y limits. Then you can explicitly set the `ylim` of the plot. Since the values in the example scales between 10 and 20, the 10 from major_ticks and 20 from minor_ticks are shown. Consider below code:

```
import matplotlib
import numpy as np
import pylab as plt

fig=plt.figure(figsize=(15, 20))
locmin = matplotlib.ticker.LogLocator(base=10.0,subs=(.1,.2,.3,.4,.5,.6,.7,.8,.9),numticks=15)

ax6 = plt.subplot(616)
plt.plot(np.random.random(1000)*4+14, 'b')
plt.plot(np.random.random(1000)*4+14, 'r')
plt.minorticks_on()
plt.ylabel('Y')
plt.yscale('log')

ax6.yaxis.set_minor_locator(locmin)
ax6.yaxis.set_minor_formatter(matplotlib.ticker.NullFormatter())
plt.tick_params(axis='y', which='minor')
ax6.yaxis.set_minor_formatter(matplotlib.ticker.FormatStrFormatter("%.1f"))

tickArr = np.concatenate((plt.yticks()[0], ax6.yaxis.get_minorticklocs()))
ylim_min = tickArr[tickArr < plt.ylim()[0]].max()
ylim_max = tickArr[tickArr > plt.ylim()[1]].min()

plt.ylim([ylim_min, ylim_max])
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, this got me on the right track. I ended up looking for the closest lower major tick and then setting the range to that + that*10 (if needed), so I ended up with at least 2 major ticks.